# How can I adjust start and end time for reoccuring meetings in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, meetings

I have a situation where I have a few reoccurring meetings in my Outlook calendar for which I want to change the start and end time for.  I didn't create the meeting in the first place, and I don't want to change the time for other users that are invited to the meeting.  I only want to move the start/end time on my calendar.  I can do this easily if I open only a single occurrence of the meeting.  However, if I open the series, I cannot.  I have Outlook 2010.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's stumped me in Outlook 2013 too. The usual time fields are missing from the appointment window.

Comment: Yes, I hate outlook for this. It should be very easy and one click away - this kind of features. I have spend a lot of time to find out this!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Recurrence button on the Appointment Series tab. When you click on the button it will bring up the recurrence details and you can change them.

Comment: That did it! The Recurrence button looked like a simple toggle button, but it wasn't.  As you suggested, it opened a dialog that let me change the start and end time (among other things).  I will award you the bounty of 50 points as soon as the site lets me (in ~ 18 hours).  Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanDeCarlo & Kevin: Finally!  Thank you for the question/answer.  I can't believe how much time I wasted trying to find out how to do something as simple as this.  Totally unintuitive.  Epic UI failure on the part of Microsoft.

Comment: Just an additional note: you have to double-click the Recurrence button to display the Recurrence dialog. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an "all day" option though.

Comment: This is a nice example of an anti-pattern as applied to user interface design.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion with this is that when you edit the time of a meeting, you do it in the first screen. But when you need to edit the time for a RECURRING meeting, you need to click on the "Reccurence" icon, then choose "Custom" to go to the pane that you originally used to set up the recurrance.

Answer (score 1):

You must also have permission.  In my situation, I was able to view but not edit the recurring appointment.  At the bottom right, it said who had created this recurring appointment.  When I logged out and logged in as that user, I was then able to adjust the appointment.

Answer (score 1):

As I am not (yet?) eligible to comment directly under a post I am trying this method...in response to maxhugen's note of 4 Mar 15 about there being no All Day option when changing the timing of a Recurring event.  This was frustrating me, too

I solved it today: open the event series, click Recurrence and then set the appointment start and end times to 00.00 and then find the "1 day" in the Duration drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the meeting in your calendar, select 'entire series'. Go to 'Meeting Series' tab, then click on 'Recurrence' icon - here you can change the time for all subsequent meetings.